# Trigger Vue router/component with next/previous click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a vue-cli, router. and I have separate components. What will be the best way to change from one page to another on next/previous click event? Thank you!

```
   // App.vue
   <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Homepage</router-link>
      <router-link to="/link_1">About</router-link>
      <router-link to="/link_2">Portfolio</router-link>
      <router-link to="/link_3">Contact</router-link>
    </nav>

    <div @click="next">Go to next link</div>
    <div @click="preview">Go to previous link</div>

   // router/index.js
   const routes = [
     { path: '/', component: home },
     { path: '/link_1', component: About },
     { path: '/link_2', component: Portfolio },
     { path: '/link_3', component: Contact },
   ]
```

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks,  this.$router.go(1) and this.$router.go(-1) do the job!

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? It uses the browser history to go from a page you visited to the next/previous one in the history

Comment: Don't you want to go from the Homepage to the About page when clicking next?

Comment: It's not what I want :( Now I tried and I figure that this is only back/forward for history record.

Comment: you should use `router.push({ path: '/foo' })`. It's the first section in the documentation I linked to. Or name your routes and use `router.push({ name: 'foo' })`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could define you `App` component

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      routes: [],
      currentRouteId: 0
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.routes = this.$router.options.routes

    // Init currentRouteId from URL
    this.refreshCurrentRouteId(this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath)

    // Handle manual page change
    this.$router.afterEach((to, from) => { this.refreshCurrentRouteId(to.path) })
  },
  methods: {
    refreshCurrentRouteId (currentPath) {
      this.currentRouteId = this.routes.findIndex(route => route.path === currentPath)
    },
    next () {
      console.log('Going to next page')

      this.currentRouteId++
      if (this.routes.length === this.currentRouteId) {
        // Go back to first route
        this.currentRouteId = 0
      }

      this.$router.push(this.routes[this.currentRouteId])
    },
    preview () {
      console.log('Going to previous page')

      this.currentRouteId--
      if (this.currentRouteId === -1) {
        // Go to last route
        this.currentRouteId += this.routes.length
      }

      this.$router.push(this.routes[this.currentRouteId])
    }
  }
}
```

It'll navigate through routes defined inside the `router/index.js` file and handle manual navigation (using `router-link` or so).